# How to make an Excel chart with a indirect range

Tags: excel, charts, excel-indirect

I want to plot the chart of 2 data series. They are in column A and B.
But their first and last line can vary and they are given from cell C1 and C2.

Charts in Excel does not seem to accept the use of the INDIRECT function.
Could you provide an example of a solution ?

Comment: Use a range of cells for the data that themselves have formulae pointing to the relevant data source.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, Sorry, but I don't understand how to do that. Would you have an example ?